# How to use Console in android

Tags: android, console

Please how can i apply this code to my android application. I am making an application that gives access to the User by entering the correct password.
I seem to be getting an error with the Console

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {

      Console c=System.console();

        String login = c.readLine("Enter your login: ");
        char [] oldPassword = c.readPassword("Enter your old password: ");

        if (verify(login, oldPassword)) {
            boolean noMatch;
            do {
                char [] newPassword1 =
                    c.readPassword("Enter your new password: ");
                char [] newPassword2 =
                    c.readPassword("Enter new password again: ");
                noMatch = ! Arrays.equals(newPassword1, newPassword2);
                if (noMatch) {
                    c.format("Passwords don't match. Try again.%n");
                } else {
                    change(login, newPassword1);
                    c.format("Password for %s changed.%n", login);

                }
                Arrays.fill(newPassword1, ' ');
                Arrays.fill(newPassword2, ' ');
            } while (noMatch);
        }

        Arrays.fill(oldPassword, ' ');

    }

    //Dummy change method.
    static boolean verify(String login, char[] password) {
        // this method always returns true in this example.
        // modify this method to verify password according to your rules.
        return true;
    }

    //Dummy change method.
    static void change(String login, char[] password) {
        // modify this method to change password according to your rules.
    }
}
```

Comment: But why you want to read from the Console? Android is GUI based platform. Secondly, in Android there is no such thing as `main`.

Comment: I know this is a complete java code.I want to know if there is anyway I can make modifications to this code so that i can apply it to my android application. Or if you know a better way that I can make my application create a new pasword that will be set as old when the user wants to change the password for the application. Take an instace of entering the screen lock code for an adroid mobile phone(it has no default code but when u enter the codes for the first time the next time it makes that code the old one)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can re-use your `verify` and `change` apis for android but you have discard whatever in the `main` method.

On Android, you will be creating an `Activity` having three `EditText` (for hide user text use `android:inputType="textPassword"`), one for each.

- Old Password
- New Password
- New Password Again

Then you ll have one button call it `Change Password`. To this `Change Password` button you can add `onClickListenr`. When user presses this `Change Password` button, you will fetch the text values from `EditText` and then user your `verify` and `change` apis to do the actual work.

You can optionally choose a `Cancel` button too.

Below is how screen will look:

[image]

Snippet of handling the `Change` button:

```
// Declared in your Activity class.
EditText editTextOldPass;
EditText editTextNewPass;
EditText editTextNewPassAgain;

String login = "";


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    editTextOldPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextOldPass);
    editTextNewPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNewPass);
    editTextNewPassAgain = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNewPassAgain);
    Button buttonChange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChange);

    buttonChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (editTextNewPass.getText().equals(editTextNewPassAgain)) {
                if (verify(login, editTextOldPass.getText().toString().toCharArray()))
                    change(login, editTextNewPass.getText().toString().toCharArray());
            } else {
                Log.i("PasswordActivity", "Passwords don't match. Try again.");
            }
        }

    });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks so much.I have done this but am having trouble getting the code to work.I would appreciate it if you can paste your edited code.

Comment: thanks Kasper I will work on this and hopefully it solves everything.will let you know.